# Setting attribute without prefix using Java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, namespaces

Using Java DOM I'm trying to set an attribute for an element without the namespace before the attribute name.

So, what I need is:

```
<documentObject xmlns="http://www.myschema.com">
    <element1 attr1="value">foo</element1>
</documentObject>
```

If I try to set the attribute as following `element1.setAttributeNS("http://www.myschema.com", "attr1", value);` I get an empty xmlns tag and additionaly a xmlns with prefix like the following:

```
<element1 attr1="value" xmlns="" xmlns:ns3="http://www.myschema.com">foo</element1>
```

If I try to set the attribute as following `element1.setAttribute("xmlns:attr1", value);` I get a prefix (xmlns) before my attribute name as shown here:

```
<element1 xmlns:attr1="value">foo</element1>
```

As for further information I create my elements as following:

```
 Element element = dom.createElementNS("http://www.myschema.com", elemName);
 element.appendChild(dom.createCDATASection("foo");
 xmlElement.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your desired output again:

```
<documentObject xmlns="http://www.myschema.com">
    <element1 attr1="value">foo</element1>
</documentObject>
```

In this document, the following statements are true:

1. `documentObject` and `element1` are in the `http://www.myschema.com` namespace.
2. **The attribute `attr1` is not in any namespace.**

While *elements* whose names are not prefixed are going to be in whatever default namespace is in effect, *attributes* whose names are not prefixed are not in any namespaces. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting):

> Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear.

So to obtain the output you desire, you should be able to just do:

```
element1.setAttribute("attr1", value);
```

Of course this all depends on the desired output being correct. If really `attr1` must be in a namespace, then your desired output is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will produce output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documentObject xmlns="http://www.myschema.com">
    <element1 attr1="value">foo</element1>
</documentObject>
```

Java Code

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class XMLTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

        Element element = doc.createElementNS("http://www.myschema.com", "documentObject");
        doc.appendChild(element);

        Element element1 = doc.createElement("element1");
        element.appendChild(element1);

        element1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("foo"));
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("attr1");
        attr.setValue("value");
        element1.setAttributeNode(attr);

        element.appendChild(element1);

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("testfile.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println("File saved!");
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I get the result in the following format:

<element1 attr1="value" xmlns="" xmlns:ns3="http://www.myschema.com">foo</element1>

Comment: I have added complete sample. Try this!